# fabricjs apply filter on base64 datasource on mobile

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, fabricjs2

I'm uploading a picture via an input type="file" and I get a picture in base64:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

I apply a filter on it in fabricjs like this:

```
    var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale();
image.filters.push(filter);
image.applyFilters();
canvas.renderAll();
```

But if the canvas with the applied filter is rendered, the picture disappear. If I remove the filter afterwards, the picture shows again.

I use fabricjs in v.2.0.0-rc.3

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having the same issue